# Unable to wget after migration from win2008 to win2016

Tags: windows, wget, windows-server-2016

We have a central package repository which we moved from win2008 to win2016(new server), after that whenever i try to do a wget from linux it just stucks, unable to download the package.

I was able to download package using wget on win2008.

I have kept the package repository on network share as well, still unable to wget.